# Disable 2 cores to meet 95w TDP

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-management, multi-core, amd-phenom

I have a [Phenom II X4 965 BE](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Phenom%20II%20X4%20965%20Black%20Edition%20-%20HDZ965FBK4DGM%20%28HDZ965FBGMBOX%29.html) CPU on a [M5A78L-M LX/BR](http://www.asus.com/br/Motherboards/M5A78LM_LXBR) motherboard. The motherboard supports processors of maximum 95W TDP. The CPU is 125W TDP.

So I disabled 2 cores of the CPU trying to avoid the maximum power dissipation. Will my motherboard be safe doing this?

Comment: I couldn't say, but I urge caution when concerned about power considerations. little else can destroy your hardware they way incompatible power requirements can.

Comment: I bought this motherboard to replace other that was supposed to be better. It is working perfectly, but there is this "problem" of 95W TDP. But I will not worry, if it explodes I will go to Intel.